# Do I need match pairs for ECC DDR4 RAM in workstation / server?

Tags: memory, ecc

I'm looking to upgrade the ECC DDR4 RAM in my workstation. It is a Dell Precision 3650 Tower with a Xeon W1350. It can take up to 4x32GB 2933Hz ECC or 2X32 3200Hz ECC.
I'm having trouble finding a match set of this.

The Nemix website was the only place were I found a set but it doesn't list the timings.
https://nemixram.com/128gb-4x32gb-ddr4-2933-pc4-23400-ecc-udimm-memory/

Also most websites consider this server memory. Most websites like CDW list server RAM as individual sticks though.

I do want ECC for reliability as the workstation does run complex models for hours.

Is a match pair or set not an important thing for this type of ram?
Should I be looking for this some other way or should I be looking for something else?

Very confused. Please help.

Comment: [Supported RAM configurations](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/fi-fi/precision-3650-workstation/prec_3650t_ss/memory?guid=guid-f1dc2c06-83a7-45ee-a462-493218648bee&lang=en-us). Apparently Dell is picky about [mixing RAM modules from different manufacturers](https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Fixed-Workstations/Dell-Precision-3650-Tower-can-t-add-RAM/td-p/7984429).

Comment: Definitely would replace the existing ram with all the same brand and type. It's just that most server ram is sold as individual sticks and not a set.